# React native realm auto update

Tags: android, ios, react-native, realm

**Implementing realm in ios/android react native app.**

I'm doing the following.

***on Splash screen load:***

**1.** post a web request for getting cars name json from server.

**2.** I'm storing cars json result in realm car object.

***on view cars page load:***

**3.** display cars from realm.

***condition:***
new car is added/update or deleted on server(data changes on server)
- *how to tell realm that data is changed and it **automatically update it in realm** also auto **update on UI without page refresh**.*

Kindly guide me how can I achieve this. Also if this is not right kindly suggest the correct way to do it.Any working example would be appreciable.

Thank you!

p.s: new to react native and realm

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the new data from server you can update your realm object in success block like this

```
realm.write(() => {
        const carsData = realm.create('cars', {
            key: value
        }, true)
    })
```

if you need the update your UI with new values you can use setState method to re-render UI with new values. I hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you! But how will I know data is changed on server? like some listener that I can use

Comment: check socket.io to listen server, sorry for late answer

Comment: May be this answer comes too late, but I'll share it nonetheless. Let me say also that I'm not a react/realm expert. So, this is my best: one of the strength of realm is exactly what you need. You can set up a Realm Object Server (or use their paid cloud service) which can be your "source of truth" and let the realm engine handle all the synching/refreshing stuff automatically. You don't even need to write explicit code for initializing your local realm instance with your remote data. This is done automatically once you have you realm instance properly set and configured to sync with your ROS